# Editing URL in AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to edit a URL , that i sent in AJAX call.

```
function saveEdit() {
  // logic for updating an existing item
                $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom/"+globalData._id.$oid+"?apiKey=veTqID_gkb74tG-yL4MGcS1p2RRBP1Pf",
                type: "PUT",
                data: JSON.stringify({  Item:Item.value , Location: Location.value , Category: Category.value , Description : Description.value , Quantity: Quantity.value}),
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
```

In the above code i want to replace "localhost" from an IP , when the website is UP. I will read the IP from a config file.

Tried concatenating strings , did not work. Any suggestions?

Expected is :

```
https://x.x.x.x/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom/
```

Comment: How are you getting the IP from the config file?

Comment: To clarify, basically you want `url: "https://" + configured_host + "/api/1/...etc...",` ?

Comment: Could you show the code you used regarding this comment: "Tried concatenating strings , did not work. Any suggestions?" 

Stephen is basically correct, as you noted. 

How are you loading information from the config file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function saveEdit() {
    var useLocalHost = false; // flag to taest if you want to do the replace or use the localhost parameter
    var localhostUrl = "https://localhost/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom/"+globalData._id.$oid+"?apiKey=veTqID_gkb74tG-yL4MGcS1p2RRBP1Pf";
    var url = useLocalHost ? localhostUrl : localhostUrl.replace("localhost","x.x.x.x");

    // logic for updating an existing item
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "PUT",
        data: JSON.stringify({  Item:Item.value , Location: Location.value , Category: Category.value , Description : Description.value , Quantity: Quantity.value}),
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var url = "https://localhost/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom/"+globalData._id.$oid+"?apiKey=veTqID_gkb74tG-yL4MGcS1p2RRBP1Pf"
if(url.indexOf(UP) !== -1){
    var IP = GetIPfromConfig();
    url = url.replace(/localhost/, IP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, how about using parameters:

```
function saveEdit(host, key) {
  // logic for updating an existing item
                $.ajax({
                url: "https://" + host + "/api/1/databases/geolocation/collections/boom/"
                     + globalData._id.$oid + "?apiKey=" + key,
                type: "PUT",
                data: JSON.stringify({  Item:Item.value ,
                                        Location: Location.value ,
                                        Category: Category.value ,
                                        Description : Description.value ,
                                        Quantity: Quantity.value}),
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
```

However, now you've pushed off where to get `host` out of the saveEdit function into the caller.

If *host* is the same host that is serving the page that's easy, it's just
 `saveEdit( window.location.hostname, myApiKey )`

If it's some *other* host, from a config file as you say (where is the config file? on your server?), you have to somehow get that to the javascript caller.
One method is to attach it to a `data-` attribute, maybe on the button or a parent div or even the body.
`<div id="thing_container" data-api-host="$configured_host">`
Using `$var` or `${var}` or whatever your server-side stack uses.

You can get that with something like

```
var elem = document.getElementById('thing_container');
var api_host = elem.getAttribute('data-api-host');
saveEdit( api_host, myApiKey );
```